# EXC_BAD_ACCESS iOS6 GM UITableTextAccessibilityElement

Tags: uitableview, exc-bad-access, ios6, nszombieenabled

i'm starting to update my app, which has been available and working all the way from iOS 2.2.1 to 5 (I still manual memory management on it, if that matters).

Now, when I run it on iOS6 GM I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS,

when I run the project with Zombie Object enabled,

I get:

-[UITableTextAccessibilityElement accessibilityContainer]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb3cacff0

wtf?

has anyone run into the same problem? how did you solve it?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XA, I got rid of it by removing some legacy threading code within my app. Something with the table's inner workings and the threads running was making it crash.

This is an app that has been around since iOS 2.2.1 and at the time the speed of the iPhone (dont recall if it was iphone 2 or 3) required an  acitivty indicator. But with iphone 4s / 5 / ipod touch 4th & 5th Generation the indicator would be showing for about half a second anyway

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on iOS 6 GM, but it's all right on iOS 5.1.
This is possibly a iOS 6 bug, it occurs when I call [tableView reloadData];

Comment: It's almost certainly _not_ a bug in iOS 6. It's far more likely that you're calling `-reloadData` from a thread other than the main thread, or you're releasing/modifying your model data on some other thread. While changes to the compiler/OS may make these *programming* errors apparent, they're still actually programming errors and not OS/Framework bugs.

Comment: @JasonCoco: accessibility in iOS is buggy, especially the newer iOS 6 stuff. My current favorite is the fact that VoiceOver can temporarily maintain references to subviews on a view that has already been removed and nilled, leading to VoiceOver continuing to navigate the focus through elements that aren't there any more.